# How to capture regex from cucumber steps

Tags: javascript, regex, gherkin, cucumberjs

I need to capture value based on regex in cucumber js steps

Use case =>

```
When I click the '2nd' item in the list
```

I want to capture '2' in the step defination of above.

I tried this in step definetion =>

```
When(/^I click the '\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th)?' item in the list$/, async function(element) {
    await helperActions.clickTopBanksListElement(element);
});
```

But couldn't able to capture '2'. Please, anyone, suggest

Comment: You can use a capture group `(\d{1,2})`

Comment: Right, `Given(/^I click the '(\d{1,2})(?:st|nd|rd|th)?' item in the list$/, (item)=>{ ... });`
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to capture the digits using parenthesis: `'(\d{1,2})(?:st|nd|rd|th)?'`

Furthermore, you don't need to limit the digits to one or two characters. Using `(\d+)` will capture one or more digits. I'm also not sure why you were trying to include the `?:` characters at the beginning of the back reference for the st, nd, rd and th abbreviations.

```
When(/^I click the '(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?' item in the list$/, async function(element) {
    await helperActions.clickTopBanksListElement(element);
});
```

Alternatively, you don't need the quotation marks:

```
When(/^I click the (\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)? item in the list$/, async function(element) {
    await helperActions.clickTopBanksListElement(element);
});
```

Giving you:

```
When I click the 2nd item in the list
```

Which reads more like how you would really write this sentence.